# Which caching method is appropriate for new version of website?

Tags: c#, angular, caching, browser-cache

I have a C#/Angular site that gets a version update every few weeks. However some users don't get the new version and it causes issues with the site. I can't seem to find a definitive answer. What should I do to fix this?

As I understand it my options are:

1. Appending a version parameter to the end of all of the .JS files generated by a Visual Studio build, which should force the files to be re-downloaded
2. Setting the Angular login token to invalidate after 24 hours, then calling a method to clear the cache on the c# side `[ResponseCache(NoStore=true,Duration=1)]` and calling a method to set it back when the token is updated.

**More Info**

Caching is enabled in Angular as far as I know. I am building a Release config, and this is in the package.json:

```
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
```

Comment: An angular production build should have the option `outputHashing` set to true, which adds cache busting hashes to all bundles. Can you confirm this is enabled for you?

Comment: @xdecdec I updated the post with the line from package.json. Does that help? Let me know if you need more info! Thanks!

Comment: Can you try if setting it to --output-hashing=all solves your issue? That should also apply the cache busting to your js files, meaning your users' browsers will always load the up-to-date version

Answer (score 0):

Use serviceworker to cache data and notify new update to the user.

Running ng add @angular/PWA in your angular project, which adds angular service worker into your project.